# Is there any way to package google script code as add-on to Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Is there any way to package Google script code as add-on to Google Sheet or lock the code so no one can view or edit the script code except specified user OR owner?

If packaging as add-on is the only option, is it going to publish the add-on somewhere in the marketplace? I do not want the packaged add-on to ve available publicly.

Comment: `Warning: Android Add-ons have been deprecated and no longer supported. New Android add-ons can't be reviewed or published. Existing Android add-ons continue to function.` So using add-ons means you have a solution that is never going to work with all versions of google sheets. (they never implemented on ios and literally banned new ones on android) You can use a web app to hide your code. Is there a reason you do not want to use a web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Yes this is possible, but it depends on what you want to do and how you wish to implement your addon.*

#### More Information:

First thing that should be mentioned, as per Google's documentation:

> All add-ons are now published to the G Suite Marketplace. Originally, add-ons were published to the Chrome Web Store, and could optionally be published in the G Suite Marketplace to make them domain-wide installable.

Google have recently started migrating the Chrome Web Store to the G Suite Marketplace and so add-ons should now all be published there. You can see the migration information [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration).

Bearing this in mind, **there are a couple of ways in which you can achieve what you are wanting to do:**

Firstly, you can go through the publishing proicess to have an add-on installed in the G Suite Marketplace. You can set the visibility to determine **who is able to install the add-on**, which can be set to your domain only and therefore not publically available. The add-on must must be associated with a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project. You can also set collaborators of the add-on - these are the only people that can edit and view the code for the add-on.

Alternatively, you can set the sharing options for the script like you would any other Drive file for the script. This isn't really recommended though - allowing people to use the add-on means that they'll have code access if unpublished, and even if not they would be able to make a copy of the script if given the script ID.

#### References:

- [Extending Google Sheets with Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/sheets)
- [Publishing an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons)
- [All add-ons now in the G Suite Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration)
- [Building editor add-ons - Collaboration](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons#collaboration)

Comment: `Warning: Android Add-ons have been deprecated and no longer supported. New Android add-ons can't be reviewed or published. Existing Android add-ons continue to function.` So if you start building an Add-on to do anything just remember it won't be compatible with all versions of google sheets so doing it a different way is always preferable.

Comment: @CodeCamper Sheets add-ons and Android add-ons are not the same thing - sheets add-ons do not work on mobile at all. This is just for extending Google Sheets on dektop.

Comment: They used to work on android and there still is existing android add-ons, and of course when you download sheets on Android it is called... sheets... Google App Script is totally compatible with the Android version of sheets so why make a solution that is suddenly going to be incompatible with all the ways you can access sheets is what I am saying.